# Node.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

(UPDATED)

Problem:
I can't return all my testing data (as the picture shows)
[No data show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAMeI.png)
What I expected should be ->

{"data":[{"id": 1,"title": "title A","content": "content A","createTime": 1612708329045,"author": "Alisa"}, {"id": 2,"title": "title B","content": "content B","createTime": 1612708333855,"author": "Alisa"}],"errno":0}

---

Error message from terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\jiann\Desktop\JS\Nodejs> node www.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jiann\Desktop\JS\Nodejs\www.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

---

I don't know where went wrong :(.
Please let me know if more details are needed, appreciate your help!

My code is below:

Code Block 1 Description:
If getting data and message successfully, show "errno":0, if not then show "errno":-1

```
class BaseModel {
        constructor(data, message) {
            if (typeof data === 'string') {
                this.message = data
                data = null
                message = null
            }
            if (data) {
                this.data = message
            }
            if (message) {
                this.message = message
            }
        }
    }
    class SuccessModel extends BaseModel {
        constructor(data, message) {
            super(data, message)
            this.errno = 0
        }
    }
    class ErrorModel extends BaseModel {
        constructor(data, message) {
            super(data, message)
            this.errno = -1
        }
    }
    module.exports = {
        SuccessModel,
        ErrorModel
    }
```

Code Block 2 Description:

set router for my blog and user. This code block will set data format in JSON, set URL path, parse query, and return 404 if no router is found.

```
const querystring = require('querystring')
    const handleBlogRouter = require('./blog-1/src/router/blog')
    const handleUserRouter = require('./blog-1/src/router/user')

    const serverHandle = (req, res) => {
        // set JSON
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')

        //get path
        const url = req.url
        req.path = url.split('?')[0]

        //parse query
        req.query = querystring.parse(url.split('?')[0])

        //set blog router
        const blogData = handleBlogRouter(req, res)
        if (blogData) {
            res.end(
                JSON.stringify(blogData)
            )
            return
        }

        //set user router
        const userData = handleUserRouter(req, res)
        if (userData) {
            res.end(
                JSON.stringify(userData)
            )
            return
        }
        
        //no router
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-type": "text/plain"})
        res.write("404 Not Found\n")
        res.end()
    }

    module.exports = serverHandle
```

Code Block 3 Description:
Use GET and POST to require data from path ->
'/api/blog/list'
'/api/blog/detail'
'/api/blog/new'
'/api/blog/update'
'/api/blog/del'

```
const { getList, getDetail } = require('../controller/blog')
    const { SuccessModel, ErrorModel } = require('../model/resModel')

    const handleBlogRouter = (req, res) => {
        const method = req.method // GET POST
        

        
        if (method === 'GET' && req.path === '/api/blog/list') {
            const author = req.query.author || ''
            const keyword = req.query.keyword || ''
            const listData = getList(author, keyword)
            return new SuccessModel(listData)
        }

        
        if (method === 'GET' && req.path === '/api/blog/detail') {
            const id = req.query.id
            const data = getDetail(id)
            return new SuccessModel(data)
        }

        
        if (method === 'POST' && req.path === '/api/blog/new') {
            return {
                msg: 'dummy'
            }
        }

        
        if (method === 'POST' && req.path === '/api/blog/update') {
            return {
                msg: 'dummy'
            }
        }

        
        if (method === 'POST' && req.path === '/api/blog/del') {
            return {
                msg: 'dummy'
            }
        }
    }

    module.exports = handleBlogRouter)
```

Code Block 4 Description:
These are my two testing data.

```
const getList = (author, keyword) => {
        //fake data
        return [
            {
                id: 1, 
                title: 'title A',
                content: 'content A',
                createTime: 1612708329045,
                author: 'Alisa'
            },
            {
                id: 2, 
                title: 'title B',
                content: 'content B',
                createTime: 1612708333855,
                author: 'Amanda'
            }
        ]
    }

    module.exports = {
        getList
    })
```

Comment: Hi @Jiann. Thanks for posting this. Could you take a look at the [Minimal, Reproducible Example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. You've included a LOT of code here and it's not clear where the issue is.

Comment: Additionally, the error message you mentioned in the title (Node.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined) isn't mentioned in your question. Please simplify the question to specify when and where you get this error.

Comment: Hi @James Thanks for your advice! Sorry i was a bit panic when facing this issue and this is my first post on stackoverflow...I trimmed up my question and hope it is easier to understand.

Comment: No problem Jiann. Looks like you have some answers now so I guess the improvements helped. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @James Actually I still do not figure out this problems...Could you help me to point out where my code problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are accessing `<?>.author`, but `<?>` is `undefined`.

For example, if your error is here:

```js
    if (method === 'GET' && req.path === '/api/blog/list') {
        const author = req.query.author || ''
//      ^^^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined
        const keyword = req.query.keyword || ''
```

This means `req.query` is `undefined`. You can use **optional chaining** if there is a *chance* something will be present:

```js
let foo = undefined;

foo.bar; // TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
foo?.bar; // => undefined
foo?.bar.baz; // TypeError: Cannot read property 'baz' of undefined
foo?.bar?.baz; // => undefined
```

Comment: I have updated my question and added more details, hope it can help you to understand what my question is. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

the error is because your server hasn't started properly so all those values you are expecting will be not a available. what command did you use to start the server?

Comment: i just typed "node www.js" to start the server on the terminal. www.js is the name i created.